# How to increment a integer variable itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

How to increment a integer variable itself in C#?

i need something the variables as

```
integer1
integer2
integer3
integer4
integer5
```

In a for loop when it is  looped i want the variables gets incremented. How can i get?

Comment: You don't, you store these values in an array of `myInteger[5]` instead and iterate over that. If you really want to do this then you might be able to using reflection, but only if they exist as properties on some object rather than local variables in your function.

Comment: do you want to increment the value for a integer identifier. or the integer identifier itself ?

Comment: i need increment of integer identifier itself. NOT the value

Comment: Identifier names are not something you can change. Period.

Comment: Is it possible to increment `string` variable/identifier atleast??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is an *array*:

```
var ints = new int[5];  // declares an array of five integers, ints[0] to ints[4]

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // do something with ints[i]
}
```

For a more in-depth introduction, have a look at the following tutorial on MSDN. It's for an old C# version, but the concepts still apply:

- [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx)

Comment: i need increment of integer identifier itself. NOT the value. Why should i post a question if i know incrementing value or holding into an array? Due to some requirement i need the integer identifier variable itself to get incremented.

Comment: The answer for your question is, as everybody is saying, using arrays. Nobody's talking about incrementing its values, but its pointer, so you can call integer[1], integer[2], integer[3],... and do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic identifier names are **not possible** in C# and any other .NET language.

You can use an array or generic list instead - these will hold a collection of your type and allow you to iterate over it.

```
var intArr = new int[5];

var intList = new List<int>(5);

foreach(var num in intList)
{
  // do something with num
}
```

Comment: i need increment of integer identifier itself. NOT the value

Comment: @sukumar - As explained, that is **not possible**. You are looking for something that has **no support** in the language. I am suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Is it possible to increment `string` variable/identifier atleast??

Comment: @sukumar - Variable names (i.e. identifiers) are not dynamic. No. You. Can't. If you explain what you are trying to achieve (instead of asking about an approach), you might get an answer that actually helps to solve the problem.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change variable names dynamically in `C#`.